# Illegal characters in path when attempting to deploy an Azure webjob via Visual Studio Online build process

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a CI build process with Azure WebJobs. I have a ASP.NET MVC5 and a WebJob project in the solution and several class library projects. I have a working Visual Studio Online (VSO) build definition already setup to deploy the MVC project. However, when I add the WebJob project to the solution the build process fails with:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (2586, 5) Copying file C:\a\1\a**\*.* to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\app_data\jobs\triggered\LoyaltyClub\*.* failed. Illegal characters in path.
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? Both the MVC and WebJob projects are using version 1.0.7 of the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish Nuget package.

Comment: Sharing this question with our internal team now. Does it build locally? Can you share the build definition?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'm using one of the new VSO build definitions rather than XAML so not sure how I go about sharing those.  I can tell you that the task that's failing is a 'Visual Studio Build' task (version 2013) with the following settings MSBuild arguments /p:OutputPath="$(build.stagingDirectory)" /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.stagingDirectory)\packages"

Comment: As a quick test can you try changing this  /p:OutputPath="$(build.stagingDirectory)"  to  /p:OutputPath="$(build.stagingDirectory)\"  if that fixes it I would say it is a bug in the targets file that does not normalize the value of OutputPath into something that has a trailing \ before trying to use it in a copy task.

Comment: Just tried that but then MSBuild fails with "MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified." Take the slash out and it starts working again